# QuickBooks Desktop PHP Sales Order API

Tags: php, quickbooks

I want to integrate QuickBooks desktop on our website.

I read the documentations and I cannot seem to find how to fetch a sales order from QuickBooks Desktop. Our data flow is this, the customer buys on our website, then we encode the purchases made by the customer on our website in the QuickBooks Desktop.

I know that we can automate the inserting of sales order but I only need to fetch the sales order so that I can update it's status in QuickBooks once the user updated it's status on our website.

BTW, I want to fetch the sales order by using its P.O. Number, the P.O. Number is auto-generated on our website which we include when encoding the sales order in QuickBooks Desktop.

So far, this is the only code that I have come up with. I haven't tested it yet because I do not know where to put the P.O. Number.

Thanks.

```
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesOrderQueryRq metadata="ENUMTYPE"iterator="ENUMTYPE" iteratorID="UUIDTYPE">

        </SalesOrderQueryRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the QuickBooks OSR:

- https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html

If you click the `XMLOps` tab, you an see the query-able fields.

```
<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<TxnID >IDTYPE</TxnID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->

<RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->

<RefNumberCaseSensitive >STRTYPE</RefNumberCaseSensitive> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
<!-- OR -->

<MaxReturned >INTTYPE</MaxReturned> <!-- optional -->
<!-- BEGIN OR -->

<ModifiedDateRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <FromModifiedDate >DATETIMETYPE</FromModifiedDate> <!-- optional -->
  <ToModifiedDate >DATETIMETYPE</ToModifiedDate> <!-- optional -->
</ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
<!-- OR -->

<TxnDateRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- BEGIN OR -->
  <FromTxnDate >DATETYPE</FromTxnDate> <!-- optional -->
  <ToTxnDate >DATETYPE</ToTxnDate> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- OR -->
  <!-- DateMacro may have one of the following values: All, Today, ThisWeek, ThisWeekToDate, ThisMonth, ThisMonthToDate, ThisCalendarQuarter, ThisCalendarQuarterToDate, ThisFiscalQuarter, ThisFiscalQuarterToDate, ThisCalendarYear, ThisCalendarYearToDate, ThisFiscalYear, ThisFiscalYearToDate, Yesterday, LastWeek, LastWeekToDate, LastMonth, LastMonthToDate, LastCalendarQuarter, LastCalendarQuarterToDate, LastFiscalQuarter, LastFiscalQuarterToDate, LastCalendarYear, LastCalendarYearToDate, LastFiscalYear, LastFiscalYearToDate, NextWeek, NextFourWeeks, NextMonth, NextCalendarQuarter, NextCalendarYear, NextFiscalQuarter, NextFiscalYear -->
  <DateMacro >ENUMTYPE</DateMacro> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- END OR -->
</TxnDateRangeFilter>
<!-- END OR -->

<EntityFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- BEGIN OR -->
  <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
  <!-- OR -->
  <FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
  <!-- OR -->
  <ListIDWithChildren >IDTYPE</ListIDWithChildren> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- OR -->
  <FullNameWithChildren >STRTYPE</FullNameWithChildren> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- END OR -->
</EntityFilter>

<!-- BEGIN OR -->
<RefNumberFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- MatchCriterion may have one of the following values: StartsWith, Contains, EndsWith -->
  <MatchCriterion >ENUMTYPE</MatchCriterion> <!-- required -->
  <RefNumber >STRTYPE</RefNumber> <!-- required -->
</RefNumberFilter>
<!-- OR -->

<RefNumberRangeFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <FromRefNumber >STRTYPE</FromRefNumber> <!-- optional -->
  <ToRefNumber >STRTYPE</ToRefNumber> <!-- optional -->
</RefNumberRangeFilter>
<!-- END OR -->

<CurrencyFilter> <!-- optional -->
  <!-- BEGIN OR -->
  <ListID >IDTYPE</ListID> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
  <!-- OR -->
  <FullName >STRTYPE</FullName> <!-- optional, may repeat -->
  <!-- END OR -->
</CurrencyFilter>
<!-- END OR -->
```

You will notice that `PONumber` is not in that list. That's because *QuickBooks does not support querying/filtering by the PO Number*.

Comment: Palmer Jr, can you help me i want to  get sales order From Quickbook  in .net but i dont able to find where can i start. I have write code for token but now i want to get sales order and save it into my local db. Please help me

Comment: @A.Goutam you can ask a new question, tag it QuickBooks, and I can answer it there.

Comment: frustrated i have already create a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509682/ but not get any response from anyone

Comment: @A.Goutam Your other question does not have enough information in it for anyone to help you. Post your code. Post what you've tried so far. Post the Google searches you did. I Googled and was able to find example .NET code extremely similar to what you needed in 2 minutes.

Comment: Palmer can you provide me any link that help me. I really mad from last 7 days and not able to find that i can use.

Comment: You need to provide more information in your question. There is not enough information in your question to be able to help you.